# jQuery Traversal Question

Tags: jquery

Quick question about jQuery and DOM traversal. Look at the code below and tell me why would someone do one over the other? Is there any reason?

this

```
jQuery("div.section").click(function(){
     jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().next().find("div.section2").css("color","#fff")
})
```

instead of this.

```
jQuery("div.section").click(function(){
     jQuery("div.section2").css("color","#fff")
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are multiple div's with a class of section2 and you want to target specific one(s) then you'd probably go with the first version - although more than likely that could be "cleaner". The second version will select all div's with a class of section2.